# SAS: How to extract X years out of Y years randomly

Tags: sas, sampling

So, There is a dataset contains Y years data in total, My question is how to select a sample that has X years out of Y years randomly.
For instance; there is 2001 to 2005 years observations

say I want two random years out of a total of 5 years data? For example (2001 and 2003; 2001 and 2002;etc)
How can i do this in a DATA step instead of using PROC SURVEY SELECTION, since I haven't reach that. If it cant be done in DATA step how to solve it?

```
data have;
    input fyear data;
    datalines;
2001 123
2002 123
2001 123
2003 123
2001 123
2003 123
2004 123
2005 123
2001 123
2003 123
;
run;
```

Comment: You "haven't reach that". Does that mean you have no access to it? And what about `proc sql`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a macro variable that holds a distinct randomized list of all years in your dataset. The first two values in the list will be random valid years.

```
proc sql noprint outobs=2;
    select fyear
    into :years separated by ','
    from (select distinct fyear from have)
    order by rand('uniform')
    ;
quit;
```

Take a look at the macro variable `&years`:

```
%put &years;

2001,2004
```

We can use this directly in an `in` statement:

```
data sample;
    set have;
    where fyear IN (&years);
run;
```

Change the value of `outobs` in PROC SQL to increase or decrease the number of random years.